# In what ways vedas give equal respect to women?

Tags: vedas, history, culture, rig-veda, women

Hindu texts present diverse and
conflicting views on the position
of women, ranging from feminine
leadership as the highest
goddess, to limiting her role to
an obedient daughter, housewife
and mother. The Devi Sukta
hymn of Rigveda, a scripture of
Hinduism, declares the feminine
energy as the essence of the
universe, the one who creates all
matter and consciousness, the
eternal and infinite, the
metaphysical and empirical
reality (Brahman), the soul
(supreme self) of everything.

so in what ways do vedas give the equality of boys and girls/ man and woman in education,self-respect, rights alloted to them and of course the other evils of society.

> **But i want verses from direct vedas.**

Comment: What do you mean by "equal respect"?

Comment: in means of equal education, rights self-respect and other evils of society.

Comment: @Fiercelord [edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/22591/edit) the question to make it clear what type of mention you're looking from scriptures.

Comment: Equality between all genders cannot be good to build happy country. So, Vedas don't give equal importance.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you already said about the Devi Sukta or the VAk Sukta which was revealed to a female Rishi or RishikA.

You must also be knowing about the fact that there are more than 25 such RishikAs to whom were revealed one or the other Riks.

I am not sure though exactly what kinds of Mantras you are searching for and whether there are any such Mantras at all that explicitly say men and women are equal. But here is one such Mantra that speaks of the "men-women equality".

The Atharva Veda Sukta 14.2 is primarily focused on marriage, selection of spouse and allied matters. The Mantra given below is part of this Sukta:

The groom says to the bride:

> Amo ahamasima sA tvam (1), **sAmA aham asmi rik tvam (2), dhauraham
>   prithvi tvam (3)**.
>
> .........
>
> He am i, she thou (1), **I am chant (SAma), thou art verse (Rik) (2), I
>   am heaven, thou art Earth (3)**.
>
> **Atharva Veda 14.2.71**

Isn't this Mantra giving equal importance to men and women?

Comment: modified one is this name for god rudra fierce god and this is fierce lord. i got fierce god as an attribute of lord rudra on wikipedia and that i modified.;)